# Install Symfony on Windows behind proxy server with NTLM authentication

Tags: php, symfony, curl, networking, proxy

I tried to downlaod and install Symfony on a server at my company...

```
c:\> php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony
```

..and got the following error (partly German, but you'll get the idea):

```
PHP Warning:  readfile(http://symfony.com/installer): failed to open stream: Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werd en, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte.
 in Command line code on line 1
```

So I downloaded it manually over the browser (which worked fine) and tried to create a new site:

```
php symfony.phar new blog
```

Now I got this error:

```
[RuntimeException]
There was an error downloading Symfony from symfony.com server:
Client error response [url] http://symfony.com/download?v=Symfony_Standard_Vendors_latest.tgz [status code] 407 [re
ason phrase] Proxy Authentication Required

[GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException]
Client error response [url] http://symfony.com/download?v=Symfony_Standard_Vendors_latest.tgz [status code] 407 [re
ason phrase] Proxy Authentication Required
```

So I did a step back to see if I can do a cURL request in a PHP script. I used the following script to try it (my company is using a proxy server with NTLM authentication):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'proxy.company.loc');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 8080);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'user:password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
echo curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

And it worked fine.

What do I have to do to be able to install and use Symfony. Where do I define the proxy, the credentials and the NTLM method? I tried adding HTTP_PROXY in the env vars as "http://user:password@proxy.company.loc:8080", but that didn't help (maybe I also have to add the auth type NTLM somewhere).

The server is a Windows Server 2012 R2. PHP version is 5.6.5 and Apache is on 2.4.12.

Thanks for any help and sorry for any grammar errors!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will describe solution which I use myself.

1. Download [cntlm-0.92.3-setup.exe](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) and install it (it will set up system service).
2. Configure cntlm.ini (C:\Program Files (x86)\Cntlm\cntlm.ini) - proxy address, no proxy, domain account etc.
3. Restart Cntlm Authentication Proxy service.
4. Set http_proxy/https_proxy to http://localhost:3128 (system wide method)
5. Try symfony installer now

Sometimes it could be a little bit slow but it works. I use this solution for all console apps that do not support integration with system wide proxy. Cntlm also works on unix based OS.

Hope that's help.

Comment: Great, thanks! I now can do the previous mentioned cURL without setting `CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH` and `CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD`. I just had to use 127.0.0.1 as `CURLOPT_PROXY` and 3128 as `CURLOPT_PROXYPORT`. I changed the proxy setting of the locale IE to the same values and it also works great.
But I stuck at step 4. How do I set the proxy settings system wide? I created an environment variable called http_proxy with the value http://localhost:3128. I also found [this post](http://goo.gl/zqdvox) and used `netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie` to set the WinHTTP-proxy settings (not sure if necessary).

Comment: Well, you do not need change proxy in IE. I use cntlm proxy mainly for symfony installer and composer. Almost all console apps from unix world knows http_proxy enviroment variable (Git for example). This is what I thought as "system wide". Real system wide proxy is in Internet options. But not all apps use it (as you know symfony.phar is one of them) and this is use case for cntlm.

Comment: [Composer does use the variable http_proxy](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#http-proxy-or-http-proxy) and it worked great for me, I was able to install Symfony with Composer. So I guess my problem is fixed, thanks a lot! :-)