# installing php symfony installer

Tags: php, symfony, proxy

**I am using this cmd**

*php -r "file_put_contents('symfony', file_get_contents('https://symfony.com/installer'));"*

**output i am getting**

Warning: file_get_contents(https://symfony.com/installer): failed to open stream
: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 in Command line code on line 1

i on proxy so that above  cmd will not work directly .

I found some solution on stack overflow
[Install Symfony on Windows behind proxy server with NTLM authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967065/install-symfony-on-windows-behind-proxy-server-with-ntlm-authentication)
 but its not working for me

I tried setting http_proxy and https_proxy env variable but it dint worked for me 
Are there any chances of  problem because of ssl ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you access `https://symfony.com/installer` in your browser? If you can, it'll download a PHAR file for you. This file is ready to be used. You can put this in your "projects" directory and use it as:

```
> php symfony.phar new blog
```

Or you can move it to a location that's in your PATH and create a bat executable file:

```
@echo off
php "C:\path\to\symfony.phar" %*
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
> symfony new blog
```

Comment: Thanks bro for help , but i am getting this error if i try using first method , may be it req internet connection 

 Downloading Symfony...
  [GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException]
  cURL error 7: Failed to connect to symfony.com port 80: Connection refused
 [GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\ConnectException]
  cURL error 7: Failed to connect to symfony.com port 80: Connection refused
new <directory> [<version>]